# How to play sounds in Java games?

Tags: java, applet, audio, clip

I'm successfully playing sounds in a Java (1.5) applet game using the following code:

```
// get an available clip to play it
Clip clip = null;
for (Clip clipTemp : players) {
    if (!clipTemp.isOpen()) {
    clip = clipTemp;
        break;
    }
}
if (clip == null) {
    // no available player found, don't play
    return;
}

clip.open(audioFormat, audioByteData, 0, audioByteData.length);

clip.start();
```

(Players are a list of clips that I open at the start with the aim to reduce latency, a line listener closes the line when the stop event is retrieved.)

The problem I'm facing is intermittent delays of upto 1 second when playing a sound. This is pretty poor.

Is there any way to improve this? Are `SourceDataLines` worth considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Applet is streaming your clip whenever you want to play it, which is why you are getting a delay as the sound file hasn't been loaded into memory yet.

It's been awhile since I have done Java applet programming, but I do remember that I used to pre-load all my clips and then subsequent calls to play would not re-open the files.

Here is some code from one of my old projects

```
Clip shoot;

private loadShootWav()
{
    AudioInputStream sample;
    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("shoot.wav"));
    shoot = AudioSystem.getClip();
    shoot.open(sample);
}

public void playShootSFX()
{
    shoot.stop();
    shoot.setFramePosition(0);
    shoot.start(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. The same sound could be required to be played multiple times. Would you suggest some sort of pooling of multiple clips for each sound effect before hand?

Comment: Yeah - I usually implement a 'SoundManager' singleton class that loads all the clips. The above code will play the sound multiple times, but reset the clip each time. If you want to say play 5 of the same sound, but mix it at slightly different intervals I'd suggest trying you load 5 clips and then when you call playSFX() increment a counter that points at whichever is the next clip to be played.

Comment: @JSmyth I'm doing something just like this, but if I open multiple AudioInputStream of the same sound file, I start getting LineUnavailableException. Can you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184650/why-am-i-getting-this-lineunavailableexception

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your code correctly, you are finding an unopened clip and opening it before playing it. It would be quicker to take opened clips and restart them. You might have to stop and reset their positions first, as shown by JSmyth in playShootSFX() example.

I am getting pretty good response with SourceDataLines. The nice thing is that they start quicker than an unopened Clip, since they start right away instead of waiting until ALL the data for the sound is loaded into RAM (which occurs each time you "open" a Clip).

But, yes, if you have a lot of little sounds that are played frequently, a clip pool is the way to go. If you want them to overlap, or always play to completion, then you need multiple copies. If not, then stop, reset to 0 and restart. But don't keep reopening! If you are doing that, you might as well use a SourceDataLine.

Comment: I'm having some issues. I think I might need to do what you've mentioned here. Can you post an example? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184650/why-am-i-getting-this-lineunavailableexception

Comment: Looking at your linked post, it seems you've already solved the problem. Very good! I haven't tried Beads myself but it does look interesting. I've heard good things about the TinySound library as well, for supporting multiple playbacks. Mostly though I've been using my own code.

Comment: Sweet. I'll have to check out TinySound. Beads is nice because it gives you "machines" (what I'm calling them) that you can plug inputs into and plug the outputs into outer machine inputs. You can filter a sound with effects, etc. The cool thing is that it handles the data lines automatically by adding together the values of all you simulataneous sounds to produce the final output.

Comment: Cool, I just checked out TinySound. It's nice and simple. The simple use cases of Beads are just as simple as TinySound, but Beads allows you to get more complex with it if you want to (where TinySound can't). Thanks for showing me TinySound!